# Drawing in turtle graphics

Tags: python, list, turtle-graphics

I am trying to parse a file into a list and then use turtle graphics to draw the shapes in the list. I managed to parse the file and return it as a list successfully, however, when I try to use turtle graphics to draw the shapes in the file I get an error. Here is the code:

```
list_of_shapes = parser.parse(local_file_name) # this will parse the file into a list
drawer = Turtle_Draw_Shape_Controller()
drawer.draw_shapes(list_of_shapes)
```

Once I try to use turtle graphics to draw the pictures, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/shapes.py, line 206, in <module>
    drawer.draw_shapes(list_of_shapes)
  File "/Volumes/shapes.py", line 184, in draw_shapes
    shape_type = shape.get_shape_type()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get_shape_type'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your shape parser function is adding tuples to the `shapes_list`, e.g.:

```
shapes_list.append(("c",cir))
```

You're then trying to use those directly as shapes. Either change the parser to just append the shape itself: `shapes_list.append(cir)`, or unpack the shape object from the tuple before using it in your `draw` method:

```
for shape_type, shape in shapes:
```

I'm not sure why you'd attach the types externally to begin with if each shape object already has a `get_shape_type` method.

Comment: I changed the code to shapes_list.append(cir) for all the shapes but it gave me this error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_shape_type' "  Everything else I left the same.

Comment: Basic debugging tip: Try `print shape` right before where you get the error, see what you have there. It should be a shape, not a list, otherwise there's something else wrong.